# Regex getting an int within fixed substrings in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bunch of strings that take this form:

> SomeText_Col{multi-digit-int}_SomeOtherText

e.g.:

- abc_Col12_ccc
- bca_abc_Col3_xyz
- bbb_aaa_Col215_f

so what is common is `_Col{multi-digit-int}_`

What I would like to do is to get the {multi-digit-int} value of each line (12,3,215 respectively for examples above).

I need to solve this with regular expression (finding indexes of substrings is not acceptable), because regular expressions can be configurable.

I have tried with `@"_Col(^\d+$)_"` but it brings no success.

Explanation would be nice. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, just remove the ^ and $

```
@"_Col(\d+)_"
```

^ only matches at beginning of string, $ only at end.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` is for beginning of lines and `$` is for end of lines. Just remove those and your regex should be working as you want it to.